# T-SQL: Get all, but join on 'not null'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

So I'm trying to get all items from a table, and then add some data if there is a joined member, otherwise keep the data empty (`null`)

What I have is this:

```
SELECT 
    t.id AS _id, 
    m.name AS name
FROM     
    tableT AS t 
INNER JOIN
    tableM AS m ON t.m_id = m.id
```

The tables look like this:

**tableT**:

```
       id        m.id
       ----------------
       1         NULL
       2         1
       3         NULL
```

**tableM**:

```
       id        name
       ----------------
       1         'Bob'
```

The desired result should be this:

```
       id        name
       ------------------
       1         NULL
       2         'Bob'
       3         NULL
```

How can I achieve this, as far as I can see `inner join` won't join on `NULL` values since they can't be matched

Comment: Change it to a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Looks like a `left outer join` to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
      t.id AS _id, 
      m.name AS name
FROM     tableT AS t 
LEFT JOIN
         tableM AS m 
ON t.m_id = m.id
```

The definition of an `INNER JOIN` will only return data where there is a match in both tables, if one table has missing data then that row will not be returned.

A `LEFT JOIN` will get all data from the first table and only matching records in the second table, allowing for `NULL` values.

A little further reading if it's useful;

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 2):

use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
      t.id AS _id, 
      m.name AS name
FROM     tableT AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
         tableM AS m 
ON t.m_id = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is Left Join:

```
SELECT 
t.id AS _id, 
m.name AS name
FROM     tableT AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
tableM AS m 
ON t.m_id = m.id
```

Please check below link for more information regarding different type of joins.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx